# Kotlin Exposed SQL query on Table with compound primary key and select all which are contained in a given List of DTO Objects

Tags: kotlin-exposed

considering the following pseudo code:

```kotlin
object EntityTable : Table("ENTITY") {
    val uid = uuid("uid")
    val idCluster = integer("id_cluster")
    val idDataSchema = integer("id_data_schema")
    val value = varchar("value", 1024)

    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(uid, idCluster, idDataSchema, name = "ENTITY_PK")
}

var toBeFound = listOf(
    EntityDTO(uid = UUID.fromString("4..9"), idCluster = 1, idDataSchema = 1),
    EntityDTO(uid = UUID.fromString("7..3"), idCluster = 1, idDataSchema = 2),
    EntityDTO(uid = UUID.fromString("6..2"), idCluster = 2, idDataSchema = 1)
)

fun selectManyEntity() : List<EntityDTO> {
    val entityDTOs = transaction {
        val queryResultRows = EntityTable.select {
            (EntityTable.uid, EntityTable.idCluster, EntityTable.idDataSchema) // <-- every row for which the compound key combination of all three
                inList
            toBeFound.map {
                (it.uid, it.idCluster, it.idDataSchema)                        // <-- has an element in 'toBeFound` list with the same compound key combination
            }
        }
        queryResultRows.map { resultRow -> Fillers().newEntityDTO(resultRow) }.toList()
    }
    return entityDTOs
}
```

how do I have to write the query that it selects

all rows of EntityTable for which the compound primary key of (id, idCluster, idDataSchema)
is also contained in the given List supposed that every EntityDTO in the List<>
also has fields id, idCluster, idDataSchema) ???

if it helps: EntityDTO has hash() and equals() overloaded for exactly these three fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to make a compound expression like:

```
fun EntityDTO.searchExpression() = Op.build { 
  (EntityTable.uid eq uid) and (EntityTable.idCluster eq idCluster) and (EntityTable.idDataSchema eq idDataSchema)
}

val fullSearchExpression = toBeFound.map { it.searchExpression() }.compoundOr()

val queryResultRows = EntityTable.select(fullSearchExpression)
```

Comment: could you extend your answer for using this on BatchUpdateStatement(FooTable) ?
also is there a BatchDeleteStatement ??? or how to do this?

Comment: Just use same `fullSearchExpression` wiith update/delete statement:
`EntityTable.delete(fullSearchExpression)`

Comment: hmmm ... when I wanna select all entries of a large list (with compound PK), like select from TableWithCompoundPK where compoundPK in (list of entitysWithCompoundPK) ... I might get a buffer overflow fast, as this creates a lot of `OR (pka and pkb and pkc) OR (...) ...)` ... There has to be a better way, as compound PKs are not THAT unusual, are they??